# JQuery: delay a toggleClass just when is adding

Tags: jquery, toggle, delay, addclass, removeclass

I built this code to change the `div.myButton` when I click on it. The code wants to allow a `.toggleClass()` on `red-text` class in `#bar` with the condition that this `.toggleClass()` must be delayed **just** when it's removing the class.

My code changes `myButton` class to `myButton2`, and adds `black-text` class to `#bar`. But it can't do the second part: the `.removeClass()` with a delay.

Here's the code

```
 $(function () {
        $('div.myButton').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('myButton2');
            $('#bar').addClass("black-text");
            $(this).removeClass('myButton').addClass('myButton2');
        });
        $('div.myButton2').click(function () {
            $('#bar').delay(1000).queue(function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("black-text");
                next();
            });
        });
 });
```

And here's the jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/jmarti/gc5XT/2/

Comment: adding and removing classes has no effect on event handlers that are already attached, and using a queue requires you to dequeue() it !

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML in the question as well—not just link to the JSFiddle.